# Export / Import only one user from Drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

I need some help/suggestion on how I can export a user from our "development" site to our "live" site. Basically we have two different environment as normal but one of the user has been testing on the "development" server and would like all his data moved over to the "live".

The problem is we can't move everything but not the user and his data themselves. Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do.  To answer fully, what do you mean by the "data" of the user, do you mean role settings, etc.  or do you mean the nodes and other items he has been working on?

If you mean the role settings, it is easiest to just manually recreate the user in the new context.  If you want nodes, look at https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export.  For other types of items, views, etc., there are similar modules which will export those items.

Comment: thanks for answering, can we "restore" a user in that case? So if we deleted a wrong user are we able to reimport him from another database (backup)?

Comment: You can do it, but it is very tricky to do.  You need a very in depth understanding of the underlying database structure.  As I said, it is easier to just recreate the user from scratch.

Comment: To do this, you need to restore values in users, users_roles, fields that reference a user, etc.  In my setup (LDAP, cross references, workbench access, etc.) it would take restoring 18-20 different tables with an average of 4-5 rows per table to be restored.  This doesn't count restoring ownership of nodes to the original author or recovering lost nodes that were deleted along with the user (depends on your specific setup whether nodes were assigned to anonymous or were deleted).  If someone offered me the job to do this, I would rejoice because I could get the new car I have been wanting.